# How to find the element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an element that clears a query after the query is made, but I can't get selenium to locate it.

Here is the xpath for the element:

```
/html/body/main/div/section[1]/div/a[2]
```

This is the html for the element:

```
<a onclick="onClearClicked()" class="btn btn--secondary btn--sm">clear</a>
```

Things that I have tried:

- Finding by using the whole xpath, css selector, class name, text
- Using css to find all buttons on the page and iterating over them until I find the right one (it doesn't find any buttons with text)

````
buttons = mydriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button")
for button in buttons:
    print(button.text)
    if button.text.strip() == "clear":
        button.click()```
````

- Exiting the iframe I was in before and using the full xpath

```
driver.switch_to().defaultContent()
```

[image: Edit: I also noticed it doesn't seem to be 'included' in the drop down like other elements (no drop down arrow next to it unlike the other elements within the same div)]

I have a work around that involves quitting the driver and reopening it for every query, but this would involve logging in and navigating to the right page every time and I'd much rather be able to just use the clear button.

Comment: What is the point of searching for the *button* if it's clearly an *anchor* (link)?

Answer (score 0):

Your html doesn't have any "button" element; it's an "a" (hyperlink) element. So, you should do:-

```js
buttons = mydriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
```

Comment: This does not work; it still won't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Using full xpath not a good way , so try the following code:

```
buttons =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='btn btn--secondary btn--sm']")
for button in buttons:
    print(button.text)
    if button.text.strip() == "clear":
        button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[.='clear']").click()
```

If you want to click the element with the text clear you can just look for an a tag with that text.

Comment: I tried that and it still won't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

The element is a *`<a>`* tag which have the innerText as ***clear***

```
<a onclick="onClearClicked()" class="btn btn--secondary btn--sm">clear</a>
```

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "clear"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn--secondary.btn--sm[onclick^='onClearClicked']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn--secondary btn--sm' and starts-with(@onclick, 'onClearClicked')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: None of these seem to work; each results in a timeout exception.

Comment: As the absolute xpath is `a[2]` presumably there is a similar `<a>` tag and you need to differentiate them wrt their ancestor.